# APT complaining about no space left on device, although there is plenty

Tags: server, apt, disk-usage

I'm having an issue with an Ubuntu server. It currently is not happy with APT for some reason and is giving me the following error:

```
SystemError: E:Could not open file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - open (28: No space left on device), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This is when the system is being deployed using Salt which I don't think will cause much of a problem (it was working fine with no changes until this morning)

`df -h` and `df -i` report there is enough space and inodes available on the system for this to run correctly.

`df -h` is as follows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.5G  3.1G  59% /
udev            1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           376M  176K  375M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       394G  199M  374G   1% /mnt
```

`df -i` is as follows:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse%  Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       524288 431873    92415   83% /
udev             477990    381   477609    1% /dev
tmpfs            480055    262   479793    1% /run
none             480055      3   480052    1% /run/lock
none             480055      4   480051    1% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb      26214400     11 26214389    1% /mnt
```

Comment: Could some process have a LARGE log file open that has eaten the space? you could try `sudo lsof | less` and look for humongous entries in the `SIZE/OFF` column.

Comment: What does "deployed using Salt" mean?

Comment: @waltinator there's plenty of space, 40% is free. Salt is a deployment tool - http://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/

Comment: Could you be running in a virtual instance and could the underlying system's disk be full? Did you check `lsof`?

Comment: @waltinator This is on Amazon AWS so I would hope the underlying system's disk would not be full

Comment: Aha! You live in Oz. Ask the man behind the curtain. Does Amazon AWS have disk quotas? Did you check lsof?